# クエリ付きURLをクエリ無しURLに301リダイレクトさせる方法です。

Tags: apache

お世話になります。

旧サイト・クエリ付きURLを新サイト・クエリ無しURLに301リダイレクトさせる方法が知りたいです。

旧サイト："http://www.example.jp/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&manufacturer_id=4&Itemid=62&limitstart=0&lang=ja"

新サイト："http://www.example.jp/brand/nike"

以下は、途中まで記述した設定です。

```
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "^option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&manufacturer_id=4" [OR]
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "^option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&manufacturer_id=4&Itemid=62" [OR]
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "^option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&manufacturer_id=4&Itemid=62&limitstart=0" [OR]
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "^option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&manufacturer_id=4&Itemid=62&limitstart=0&lang=ja" [OR]
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "^option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&manufacturer_id=4&Itemid=62&limitstart=0&lang=en" [OR]
RewriteRule　パターン http://www.example.jp/brand/nike [R=301,L]
```

orailly「Apache クックブック」を見ながら設定をしているのですが、RewriteRule で正規表現パターンを設定するところで躓いています。何を設定したらよいのか見当がつきません。

ご教授の程、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.jp/brand/nike [R=301,L]
で良いんじゃないでしょうか？